# How to display HTML in Android view?

Tags: android, json, webview, retrofit

I'm sending a Retrofit GET request to the API which returns a single JSON object with entire HTML page inside this object written as a String. How do I display that inside an Android app? What's the go-to practice for this example? WebView or something else?

Comment: Theres a webView.loadString (or similar) that I dont remember exactly

Comment: If you want only to show HTML formatted text, the HTML.from(stringText) returns a Spannable that can be set as the text of a TextView

Comment: loadData did the job right. But there's another issue now. The HTML has links in it, most notable a link that says back on it, but it's obviously an http link, rather than an Android View link, so clicking that takes me back to browser. I don't suppose there's any solution for that?

Comment: You can use WebView or use something like HtmlTextView, wich fetches data from html and trasform it to Spannable https://github.com/PrivacyApps/html-textview

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [webView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) like this:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
webview.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", null);
```

Comment: Yep, that worked.